# How to Disable or hide checkbox for specific rows Grid with CheckboxModel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a grid with check-box model and I want to disable some of the check-boxes on certain condition.

1. Don't want to use renderer to override the DOM element.
2. Want to do something like this.....

   ```
   grid.getStore().load({          
     scope: this,          
     callback: function(records, operation, success) {            
       if (success) {              
         var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();              
         Ext.each(records, function(record) {                
           if (record.data.chkd) {
             var row = record.index;
             // console.log(record.index);                  
             sm.select(row, true);                  
             // HERE WANT TO DISABLE THE CHECKBOX FOR THE PARTICULAR RECORD
           }
         });              
       } else {              
         //alert(success);
         //console.log(operation.exception);
       }
     }
   });
   ```

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: By Using renderer we can disable these checkboxes but the problem is when we will try to use grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection(); to get the selected records it wont work. So we have to manually check the records we selected...

Comment: I used checkcolumn and solved this as per this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042052/extjs-checkcolumn-disable-for-some-rows-based-on-value

Comment: OP do you mind answering this question with your answer?